# How to test if the given element is the first child

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a javascript function to test if an element is the first child...

This is my code:

```
$el = document.getElementsByClassName("b")[0];
$firstEl = $el.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("a").firstChild;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bf2ae5tt/

Why it does not work?

Comment: Because you're dealing with a NodeList, not a single element. I suppose you want to loop.

Comment: shouldn't "firstChild get the first child of the list?

Comment: What do you mean by "the first child." The first child of *what*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `$firstEl = $el.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("a")[0]` instead of `firstChild`

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you, you want to check the *first* `a` to see if it's the first child of the *first* `b`, then you need another `[0]`:

```
$el = document.getElementsByClassName("b")[0];
$firstEl = $el.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("a")[0].firstChild;
// Here ---------------------------------------------^^^
if ($el === $firstEl) {
    // ....
}
```

But I would use `querySelector` instead, which has better support (basically, it's in IE8 whereas `getElementsByClassName` isn't) and it returns the first element it finds rather than finding them all and returning a list:

```
$el = document.querySelector(".b");
$firstEl = $el.parentNode.querySelector(".a").firstChild;
if ($el === $firstEl) {
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
   $el = document.getElementsByClassName("b")[0];

   if($el.parentNode.children.length > 0){
       $firstEl = $el.parentNode.children[0];
   }

   console.log($el == $firstEl);
```

Using `firstChild`

```
  $el = document.getElementsByClassName("b")[0];

   $firstEl = $el.parentNode.firstChild;

   console.log($el == $firstEl);
```

will work if your dom is

```
   <div class="p"><div class="a b"></div><div class="a"></div></div>
```

not when your dom is

```
  <div class="p">
     <div class="a b"></div>
     <div class="a"></div>
  </div>
```

because any whitespace in between tags will cause `#text` node to be inserted

[node.firstChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.firstChild)